# Google Analytics Reporting API V4, User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm facing an issue while using the googleapis library version 118.0.0 to make a request to the Google Analytics Reporting API. I'm using the new version 4 of the Analytics API.

I'm using the method `google.analyticsreporting('v4').reports.batchGet(requestParams)`, but I'm encountering the following error:

```
{
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden"
}
```

Here's the complete code snippet:

```
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'];
const privateKey = ga_private_key.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');

const jwt = new google.auth.JWT({
  email: ga_client_email,
  key: privateKey,
  scopes
});

await jwt.authorize();

const requestParams = {
  auth: jwt,
  resource: {
    reportRequests: [
      {
        viewId: gaview,
        dateRanges: [
          {
            startDate,
            endDate
          }
        ],
        dimensions: [
          { name: "ga:date" },
          { name: "ga:eventAction" },
          { name: "ga:pagePath" }
        ],
        metrics: [
          { expression: "ga:users" },
          { expression: "ga:pageviews" },
          { expression: "ga:totalEvents" }
        ],
        orderBys: sort ? [{ fieldName: sort }] : undefined
      }
    ]
  }
};

const response = await google.analyticsreporting('v4').reports.batchGet(requestParams);
```

I have verified the following information:

The user permissions are correctly set to access the Google Analytics profile. The user has administrator access and is listed as an owner in the Google Cloud Platform under "Accounts and Services".

I'm using version 118.0.0 of the googleapis library.

I'm authenticating correctly with the provided credentials when generating the key.

However, I continue to receive the aforementioned error. Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

I appreciate any assistance provided.

I performed the entire process of creating Analytics and configuring the user, but it still kept returning the same error.